# R: C symbol name not in load table - error in linking with external .c files

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp, ode

I am trying to use the **Rsundials** package to solve a system of Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) using [SUNDIALS](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html). First, I am trying to run the example in the manual.

Rsundials can be used to solve the ODEs when the right hand side of the ODEs is described in a C file.

First, the ODEs are described in a C file (example program from the package)

```
#include "include/nvector/nvector_serial.h"
#include "include/sundials/sundials_dense.h"
#define Ith(v,i) ( NV_DATA_S(v)[i - 1] )

int rhs(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *f_data){
       realtype y1, y2, y3;
       y1 = Ith(y,1); y2 = Ith(y,2); y3 = Ith(y,3);
       /* Change values of ydot here using Ith(ydot,i) */

       double L = 49.3;
       double a21 = 0.011; double a12 = 0.012;
       double a31 = 0.0039; double a13 = 0.000035;
       double a01 = 0.021; double a02 = 0.016;
       Ith(ydot, 1) = -(a01 + a21 + a31)*y1 + a12*y2 + a13*y3 + L;
       Ith(ydot, 2) = a21*y1 - (a02 + a12)*y2;
       Ith(ydot, 3) = a31*y1 - a13*y3; 
       return(0);
}
```

saved in a file `test_rsundials.c`. The file is then compiled using the following command in the terminal

```
R CMD SHLIB ./test_rsundials.c
```

**The file compiles without any error message** and I see `test_rsundials.so` and `test_rsundials.o` in my directory being generated.

Then I use the `dyn.load` to load the package -

```
dyn.load("/ .. path .. /test_rsundials.so")
```

No error message in the step above also, finally I call the cvode solver using the following commands (as shown in the manual of the package)

```
library(Rsundials)
vals  <- cvodes(c(0.0,0.0,0.0), seq(0,400,20),"test_rsundials","rhs",rtol=1e-4,atol=c(1e-8,1e-14,1e-6),verbose=T)
```

This generates the error -

```
Error in .Call("cvodes", PACKAGE = "Rsundials", as.double(y), as.double(times),  : 
  "cvodes" not available for .Call() for package "Rsundials"
```

I also tried the following command

```
yvals  <- .Call("cvodes",package="Rsundials",c(0.0,0.0,0.0), seq(0,400,20),"test_rsundials","rhs",rtol=1e-4,atol=c(1e-8,1e-14,1e-6),verbose=T)
```

which gives me the error

```
Error in .Call("cvodes", package = "Rsundials", c(0, 0, 0), seq(0, 400,  : 
  C symbol name "cvodes" not in load table
```

I am not sure how can I get around it, or what it means. I am pasting the code from `cvodes` below for reference

```
function (y, times, package, rhs, fndata = NULL, jacfunc = NULL, 
    rootfunc = NULL, numroots = 0, rtol = 1e-06, atol = 1e-06, 
    maxnumsteps = 500, maxstep = 0, verbose = FALSE, lasttime = FALSE) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(y)) 
        stop("Error: 'y' must be numeric")
    if (!is.numeric(times)) 
        stop("Error: 'times' must be numeric")
    if (!is.character(package)) 
        stop("Error: 'package' must be a character vector")
    if (!is.character(rhs)) 
        stop("Error: 'Right Hand Side function must be a character vector")
    if (!is.null(jacfunc) && !is.character(jacfunc)) 
        stop("Error: 'jacfunc' must be a character vector")
    if (!is.null(rootfunc) && !is.character(rootfunc)) 
        stop("Error: 'rootfunc' must be a character vector")
    if (!is.null(rootfunc) && numroots <= 0) 
        stop("Error: numroots must be greater than 0")
    if (!is.numeric(numroots)) 
        stop("Error: 'numroots' must be numeric")
    if (!is.numeric(rtol)) 
        stop("Error: 'rtol' must be numeric")
    if (!is.numeric(atol)) 
        stop("Error: 'atol' must be numeric")
    if (!is.numeric(maxstep)) 
        stop("Error: 'maxsteps' must be numeric")
    if (!is.null(fndata) && !is.numeric(fndata)) 
        stop("Error: Data arguments must be numeric")
    s = 1
    rhs = getNativeSymbolInfo(rhs, PACKAGE = package)$address
    jfunc = NULL
    if (!is.null(jacfunc)) 
        jfunc = getNativeSymbolInfo(jacfunc, PACKAGE = package)$address
    rofunc = NULL
    if (!is.null(rootfunc)) 
        rofunc = getNativeSymbolInfo(rootfunc, PACKAGE = package)$address
    solutions = .Call("cvodes", PACKAGE = "Rsundials", as.double(y), 
        as.double(times), rhs, as.double(fndata), jfunc, rofunc, 
        as.integer(numroots), as.integer(s), as.double(rtol), 
        as.double(atol), as.integer(maxnumsteps), as.integer(maxstep), 
        as.integer(verbose), as.integer(lasttime))
    if (lasttime == TRUE) 
        rows = 1
    else rows = length(times)
    solutions <- matrix(solutions, rows)
    col <- c()
    for (i in 1:length(y)) col[i] <- paste("y", i, sep = "")
    if (lasttime == TRUE) 
        dimnames(solutions) <- list(times[length(times)], col)
    else dimnames(solutions) <- list(times, col)
    solutions
}
<environment: namespace:Rsundials>
```

Also pasted below are details about my R

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.1.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.1.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

I read that this might be 64-bit v/s 32-bit compilation issue, I am not sure how I can specify compilation in 64-bit flag. I am a newbie at both R and C, so any help will be much appreciated!!

**Posting an update --** I read that this error might be due to linking with library issues. I looked at the [src](https://github.com/cran/Rsundials/tree/master/src) folder of this package, and the there is a file `Makevars.old` which implies that I might need to link with the libraries

```
PKG_CFLAGS=-w

PKG_LIBS=-L. -lsundials_cvodes -lsundials_ida -lsundials_fida -lsundials_nvecserial
```

**NOTE - The package manual says that "Installation of SUNDIALS is not a prerequisite for the package".**  So I have stuck all the files in `src` folder of this package in my project folder (so hopefully there are no file not found errors).

Now I tried to compile with the following commands in the terminal

```
export PKG_CFLAGS="-w"    
export PKG_LIBS="-L. -lsundials_cvodes -lsundials_nvecserial"
R CMD SHLIB test_rsundials.c sundials_dense.c nvector_serial.c
```

I get the following error now

```
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include   -w -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c nvector_serial.c -o nvector_serial.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o nvector_serial.so nvector_serial.o sundials_dense.o test_rsundials.o -L. -lsundials_cvodes -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -lsundials_cvodes
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nvector_serial.so] Error 1
```

Although, I do see three new `.o` files (`test_rsundials.o`, `nvector_serial.o` and `sundials_dense.o`) are generated

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Read the manual for `cvodes` in the `Rsundials` manual. Especially the `package` argument. You need to `dyn.load` your `test_rsundials.so` before calling `cvodes`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I do `dyn.load` after compilation, I forgot to add that in the post. I have now edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend you link into building a package against the external library.  *Many* packages do that with Rcpp, and you will hence have a large number of *working* examples to learn from.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Thanks for your comment. Due to my my limited R and C skills, I am not able to understand your comment regarding building a package against external library. I am right now, just trying to use `Rsundials` to solve a system of ODEs. However, the manual itself has been less than useful, example program in the PDF had errors so I had to dig out the working C file from source code. Even after that I am not able to get a working example. I have posted an update (above) regarding linking to SUNDIALS library while using `R CMD SHLIB`, could you please take a look?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can solve the issue. The package has had no maintenance since 2012. It uses functions which are ignored. You should send an email to the author.

Comment: Thanks. I have written to the author, waiting for the author's response now but I am not very hopeful.

Comment: I've had a further look at the source code of the package. it needs a correct and proper `NAMESPACE` file. All the error messages you got are as expected.

Comment: @SN248. Have you received a reply from the author?

Comment: No, I have not received any reply from the author.

Comment: I sent  a mail to CRAN about this package. I was told to contact the maintainer and if I don't receive a reply to contact CRAN again. I will also contact the author and do a wait-and-see what happens. In case of no reply in a reasonable amount of time I'll contact CRAN again so that they can remove the package and archive it and possibly orphan it. I'll let you know what happens.