# Setting a directory path to a dynamically linked library in an R package

Tags: c, r, dll

What is the proper way to load in a dynamically linked library (i.e., a `.so` file) when writing an R package? The only solution that has worked for me so far has been to specify the full path to the `.so` file, e.g.:

`dyn.load('/FULL/PATH/TO/MY/R_PACKAGE/src/my_file.so')`

Obviously, this approach will not work for a CRAN/Bioconductor submission since the .so file will not be located. As such, I have (unsuccessfully) tried the following alternatives:

1) `library.dynam()`

2) `library.dynam('my_file.so')`

3) `library.dynam('my_file.so', 'R_PACKAGE')`

4) `system.file("src", "my_file.so", package = "R_PACKAGE")`

Related links: [R: C symbol not in load table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853377/r-c-symbol-not-in-load-table), [R: C symbol name not in load table - error in linking with external .c files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443730/r-c-symbol-name-not-in-load-table-error-in-linking-with-external-c-files).

Just to be crystal clear, users of my R package may obviously set any arbitrary working directory on their computers. The only way a full path approach (as shown above) would ever work is if they set their working directory to `/FULL/PATH/TO/MY/R_PACKAGE/src`, which is (of course) impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this, as described in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#useDynLib), is:

> 1.5.4 useDynLib
>
> A `NAMESPACE` file can contain one or more `useDynLib` directives which allows shared objects that need to be loaded.* The directive
>
> `useDynLib(foo)`
>
> registers the shared object `foo`** for loading with `library.dynam`. Loading of registered object(s) occurs after the package code has been loaded and before running the load hook function. Packages that would only need a load hook function to load a shared object can use the `useDynLib` directive instead.
>
> `*` NB: this will only be read in all versions of R if the package contains R code in a R directory.
> `**` Note that this is the basename of the shared object, and the appropriate extension (.so or .dll) will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Quick points:

- Why do you need to ship a `.so` file?  This would preclude uploads to common repos like CRAN which will not accept binary content
- You can compute the full `/FULL/PATH/TO/MY/R_PACKAGE/src/my_file.so` by using `system.file("src", "my_file.so", package="R_PACKAGE")` (but then make sure you actually install a `src/` which is not standard)
- In *all other cases* (as pointed out by @BenBolker) R will know how to create the dynamic library and load it for you.  Every package with compiled code does that.  Just drop your source code into `src/` and you are (essentially) done.